# raspberry pi usb dac/amp

Tags: usb, audio

Can a raspberry pi be used to build an audio usb digital-analog-converter/amplifier? If it is possible I would really appreciate a few tips on how to get started. I have a little background in electrical engineering so I would not mind reading up on software amps/dsp.

Comment: To *build* one?  Perhaps with difficulty, but not even remotely effectively in comparison single-chip options off the shelf or general purpose microcontrollers/eval boards that are more easily configured for use as a USB device.  To be used *with* one, *hosting* such a USB device, yes, with some constrains.

Comment: You can get decent USB-DACs for about 60€, so why you would spend 40€ plus (Pi + power supply + case) and time I don't know. That is, unless it's the tinkering you want.

Comment: Yes, it's to learn c++ embedded programming and some microelectronics. I'm a student.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use a high-end DAC and a Raspberry Pi to make an audiophile-quality music player.

http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/digital-source/201364-raspberry-pi-new-diyers-digital-hub-16.html

http://www.audiohobby.com/raspberry-pi-for-audiophiles/